# How can i populate a string value to a realtime firebase database with out creating a child nodes from android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to add a string values to a realtime firebase database with the firebase UID being the name and the string being the value. When I use the below code it makes the UID a parent node and set the value to a child node.

`ReferralCode referralCode = new ReferralCode(refCode); databaseReference.child("referralCodes").child(userId).setValue(referralCode);`

[image]

I wanted the values to be populated as the second one. But with the above code,i get the first result. I'm going to search for the referral codes afterwards,so i think it would be faster if the values are populated as the second one to avoid accessing a child node which will be time consuming for large database entities.

Comment: How about you try databaseReference.child("referralCodes").child(userId).setValue(refCode);

Comment: As explained above, databaseReference.child("referralCodes").child(userId).setValue(refCode);  creates a child node with a name refferalCode just like the first entity.

Comment: Your RefferalCode is a Model you created which probably has the field named refferalCode = 1234567. After you create using RefferalCode as a type of the variable you are sending it will automatically create Child with the structure that your java class has. But if you send the value as a String/Int or something else, then it should use the key(userId): value(refCode). I said refCode because I saw that in the line above you are using it as a parameter for the RefferalCode constructor. So my line of code is not the same as yours.

Comment: There is not enough here to go on. What is `ReferralCode`? Also: what are "first" and "Second" in "I wanted the values to be populated as the second one. But with the above code,i get the first result"? Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to increase the chances that we can help.

Comment: I just tested my claims above and it works. I'll be posting an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using a `Model` like you created `ReferralCode` and using it to with `.setValue(referralCode)` then `Firebase` will automatically create it as the child with attributes your `ReferralCode.java` has. Example below:

```
public class Restaurant {
    private int code;
    private int type;
    private String name;
}
```

So if I create a variable `Restaurant tempRest = new Restaurant(111, "Restoran DM", 0)` and use it like this:

```
database.child("restaurants").child("1st restaurant").setValue(tempRest);
```

Firebase will create something like this:

```
restaurants
     1st restaurant:
          code: 111
          name: "Restoran DM"
          type: 0
```

But if you use `String` in `setValue()` like this:

```
String someValue = "some value";
database.child("restaurants").child("awpjawpdaw").setValue(someValue);
```

it will give you what you want. Example, I used this:

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String refCode = "1231231";
database.child("restaurants").child("wadawdapwodawp").setValue(refCode);
```

and here is what happened in database:

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy coding!

Comment: Is there an easier way you recommend to search 'refCode' string values,to check if it exist?

Comment: I don't really follow your question, can you explain a bit better what you mean by that?

Comment: So i have a realtime database with referalCodes as a parent and UID and string values as a name: value pair respectively. So what do you think i should do to search the string values to check if the user input exist?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to "loop" through your database children and check if the child with a particular value exists. For that you can use Query, like this: Query refQuery = database.child("referalCodes").orderByValue().equalsTo(STRING).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener ()) .... This way it will search the database and check if there is a value equals to the provided STRING. If it's found you'll get that object as DataSnapshot otherwise DataSnapshot will be empty.

Comment: For more, check this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query

Comment: Thank you very much! you have been a great help ;)